# How to load subtitles automatically by playing video

Tags: video, subtitle

```
<iframe class="vframe" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ydayUPe2Ifk?cc_load_policy=1"></iframe>
```

This is my try to load subtitles automatically by playing video, and not by clicking on `cc` button.

But it doesn't work. I still need the `cc` click.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ydayUPe2Ifk?rel=0&hl=sr&cc_load_policy=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```